# How to read the firebird databases query result size?

Tags: c, malloc, firebird

I am doing C interface with firebird databases. I did some query operations. I would like to know how to read the result size?

Below is the code. I have created and inserted some values into the table.I would like to read the size of the result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "/Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Versions/A/Headers/ibase.h"

static char *createTable="CREATE TABLE newex (Id int)"; //query for creating data table
static char *Insertvalues="INSERT INTO newex values (1)";//doing insertion into the   

//above created table

int SQLOpen(void)
{
    ISC_STATUS          status_vector[20];
    isc_tr_handle       transactionHandle = NULL; //transaction handle
    isc_db_handle       database = SQLGetDatabase();//database handle
    char                logInData [256], *dpb, *p;
    short               bufferLength;
    User_Credentials    credentials;

    sprintf(logInData, "%c%c%c%c%c%c%s%c%c%s",      isc_dpb_version1,
                                                    isc_dpb_num_buffers,
                                                    1,
                                                    90,
                                                    isc_dpb_user_name,
                                                    strlen("SYSDBA"),
                                                    "SYSDBA",
                                                    isc_dpb_password,
                                                    strlen("masterkey"),
                                                    "masterkey"); //passing user //credentials to connect to the database

    bufferLength = strlen(logInData);

    if (isc_attach_database(status_vector, strlen(DATABASE_PATH), DATABASE_PATH, &DatabaseHandle,bufferLength, logInData)) // connecting to database
    {
        SQLTestForErrors(status_vector);
        throw(ConnectionError, "");
    }
return 1;
}
char** SQLQuery(char *query, uint maxRows)
{
    isc_tr_handle   transactionHandle = NULL;
    isc_db_handle   database = SQLGetDatabase();
    short           bufferLength;
    char            dpb_buffer[256], *dpb, *p;
    ISC_STATUS      status_vector[20];


    isc_start_transaction(status_vector, &transactionHandle, 1, &database, 0, NULL);

    if (isc_dsql_execute_immediate(status_vector, &database, &transactionHandle, 0, query, 1, NULL)) //query operations 'create/insert'
    {
        SQLTestForErrors(status_vector);
        throw(QueryError, "");

    }
    isc_commit_transaction(status_vector, &transactionHandle);
   return testString;
}

int main()
{
    //struct Folder_table;
    e4c_using_context(E4C_TRUE)
    {

        SQLOpen();
        SQLQuery(createTable);
        SQLQuery(Insertvalues);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't in advance: the result set is materialized while you are reading rows (using `isc_fetch`): the final number of rows is not known until you have read all rows (at which point you can either have counted it yourself, or query it with an info request).

However I notice that you try to use `isc_dsql_execute_immediate`. You can only use `isc_dsql_execute_immediate` for ddl and for queries that produce one row (you need to prepare and execute for multiple rows).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. When I perform any (here in the example I did for create and insert) operations and execute it, can't I read the result size? I want to read the result size and then Allocate() ASCII tablebuffer equal to result size.

Comment: That is what I said: you can't ask for the total number of rows. When you use `isc_fetch` you can specify the number of rows to retrieve in one call.

Comment: I am searching for ISC_fetch command in firebird. I cannot find it. Say,I have created a table and inserted 3 rows in it (for example: I n the above code, I have inserted 3 row values for the column ID)and I want to know the size ( I will specify 3 rows to isc_fetch). Could you please post the code how to display the size.

Comment: @user3723478 I usually only work with a wire protocol implementation in Java, so I don't know all the C functions by heart. It is called `isc_dsql_fetch()` and is described on page 337 of the Interbase 6.0 API Guide; however it looks like it only fetches one row at a time (contrary to the wire protocol which allows specifying the fetch size)